# Jquery Ajax data method is changing a div to a text input field

Tags: ajax

I'm using ajax to send form data (composed of multiple text fields, and one file upload) to php to insert it into a sqldb. The script sends back a json encoded array that includes data of two text fields, title and address; and the complete URL for the file that was uploaded called ad_link by the array).

Jquery Ajax uses this data  to populate some div elements according to their class name. The values are getting put into the div element.

However, it is making the div elements look like textfields (just like the ones from the form used to originally send the values). I've checked the classes to make sure everything matches up correctly and that they are unique for their respective function. This page uses bootstrap and jquery. How can I troubleshoot or fix this?

```
    <body>
    <!--Form-->
    <form name="data-form" class="data-form" method="post" action="add-list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <fieldset >
        <input class="fileUpload" name="flyer" type="file"  />
      </fieldset>
      <textarea name="title" id="title"></textarea>
      <textarea name="address" id="address"></textarea>
      <button id="nxtbutttwo" class="btn btn-primary avatar-save" type="submit">Save Listing</button>
    </form>

    <!--Elements to populate upon ajax success-->
    <div class="aadded_display">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div><a class="aad_link" href="" target="_blank">
            <div class="atitle"></div>
            </a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="aaddress"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!--Jquery Ajax-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $(".data-form").submit(function() {
            data = $(this).serialize();
            if (confirm("good?"))       {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "add-list.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                              if (response.success) {
                                  $("#modal1").modal('hide');
                                $(".aadded_display").show();
                                $(".atitle").html(title);
                                $(".aadress").html(adress);
                                $("a.aad_link").html(ad_link);
                                }
                              else {
                                  console.log("An error has ocurred: sentence: " + response.sentence + "error: " + response.error);
                              }
                          },
                          error: function() {
                              alert("An Error has ocurred contacting the server. Please contact your system administrator");
                          }
                      });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
    </script> 
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from the ajax request is held in the `response` object, which you use to check the success but not to fill the divs.

```
$(".atitle").html(response.title);
$(".aadress").html(response.adress);
$("a.aad_link").html(response.ad_link);
```

For the textboxes in the divs this occurs because some browsers create global variables for elements in the dom with their ids, so `title` is the title textarea and you're placing a copy of it in the `.atitle` div.

Comment: so to fix textarea I would need to rename the objects in the json array? thank you by the way @musa